# Getting Result from a Prolog Query in C# using SWI-Prolog C#

Tags: c#, prolog, swi-prolog

I am writing a GUI for a prolog file using C# using SWI-Prolog, however I don't know how to get the solution from a query into some strings.

The query direct_evening_flight(london,edinburgh) in pl returns the some days of the week for instance Monday, Tuesday, Thursday.

If I execute the query in C#

```
PlQuery q = new PlQuery("direct_evening_flight(london,edinburgh).")
```

It automatically print the result into the console. However I want to receive the result one by one into a string variable instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your `direct_evening_flight/2` predicate into a `direct_evening_flight/3` predicate where the last variable will hold the results from your query. This way the query won't output to the standard output but to this variable instead.

Comment: Is there any way that I can capture the standard output into a string instead.?

Comment: @W00f: I don't know of a correct way to do that, but maybe there is! Sorry for not being of much help there ;(